# How to remove indent left on the widget Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Can I somehow remove this indentation? I know that I can remove the first column, but then I can not insert the image.[image: Treeview Image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(master)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Directory', anchor='w')
        self.tree["columns"]=("num_files")
        self.tree.heading('num_files', text='Number of files', anchor='w')

        self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('icon.png'))

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="Dir %d" % (i+1), values=(15), open=False, image=self.image_tk)
        self.tree.pack(expand=1,fill="both")

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Image related parts seem to be redundant.

Comment: @Nae I described the problem. Attached skrnshot. Added the full program code. What else is needed?

Comment: Sure it's almost perfect but the indentation's there w/o the required image _in_ the code, which makes the code a bit un-minimalistic. Or if the indentation's no there, w/o the icon.png then please emphasize that.

Comment: @Nae As an image, you can take any picture. To implement my task, the icon is required. In addition, I know the solution to the problem without using the icon.

Comment: I think it would help to provide that information too then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the indentation you're referring to is the left side of the first column (left of all the icons), you can adjust the entire widget padding as needed. For your application, start with:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(master, padding=[-15,0,0,0])
```

Comment: Of course, not the best solution, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

What you have highlighted in red is the area in which the Treeview's indicator resides -- the *open* or *close* toggle icon -- that is shown if any of the `Item` objects contain *subitems* of their own.

One way to accomplish removing that area would be to just remove the indicator altogether while using a ttk theme that allows you to do so.

```py
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('default')
s.configure('Treeview.Item', indicatorsize=0)
```

> This approach seems to only work for the `default`, `clam` and `classic` themes on Windows 10.  For other themes, Ron's answer may be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

The ttk Style allows for changing the layout of all widgets. If you 'simply' remove the indicator from the layout, the indentation disappears.

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.layout('my.Treeview.Item',
         [('Treeitem.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
             # The next line is removed from the layout, removing the indicator
             # ('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
             ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
             ('Treeitem.focus', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': '', 'children': [
                 ('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})
                 ]})
             ]})
             ]
         )
# Use your customized style for the Treeview widget
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(master, style='my.Treeview')
```

Comment: Thanks. This works even with the default windows style (however it is currently called? "modern"?). The accepted answer removed the border of the treeview in my case :(